# "jboss invoker not bound" while using selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium, jboss

i am trying to use selenium 2.25.0 with jboss, and seam. I use the following codes:

```
@Test
public void testRegistration() throws InterruptedException {
    DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(
            new WebDriverCommandProcessor("http://localhost:8080",new FirefoxDriver()));
    selenium.open("*****");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("main_form:name", "***");
    selenium.type("main_form:password", "***");
    selenium.click("main_form:login_button");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    Assert.assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("****"));
    selenium.click("logout");
    selenium.close();
}
```

but after the test, it fails to stop the server and gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: invoker not bound]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1352)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:219) Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: invoker not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1346)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because for some reason jboss runs its rmi related actions on port 4444 and selenium also runs on 4444. change the port of selenium (easier to do) and youre in business.

yay, answered my own question.